# Call functions from sources directly in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript

For a website there is this function under sources with the code:

```
betSlipView.prototype.stakeOnKeyUp = function(_key) {

    var model = ob.slip.getModel(),
        defval = ob.cfg.default_bet_amount;
        selector = toJqId(["#stake-", _key].join('')),
        stake_box = $(selector),
        spl = stake_box.val();

    if(spl != defval) {
        spl = ob.slip.cleanFormatedAmount(spl);
        if(spl === '' || isNaN(spl)) {
            spl = 0;
            $(selector).val('');
        }

        model.setBetStake(_key, spl);
        $(toJqId(['#ob-slip-estimate-', _key].join(''))).html(
            model.getBet(_key, 'pretty_returns')
        );
    } else  {
        $(selector).val(defval);
        model.setBetStake(_key, defval);
        $(toJqId(['#ob-slip-estimate-', _key].join(''))).html(
            model.getBet(_key, 'pretty_returns')
        );
    }

    //Update bonus amount
    try {
        var offers = model.getBet(_key, 'offers');
    }
    catch(err) {
        var offers = "";
    }

    if(offers !== "" && typeof offers['STLWIN'] !== "undefined") {
        this._handleAccumulatorBonusElements(_key, offers['STLWIN']);
    };

    // potential returns for this bet
    this.updateTotals();
};
```

I cannot figure out how to (if possible) call this function directly from the console. Firstly, when I try to write `betSlipView` in the console, it cannot be found. Consequently if I copy the code to the console to define the function, `betSlipView` is still not found and if I try to change the function name, there are some names in the function body that cannot be found either. I wish to call this function with certain arguments, is this possible?

The whole code can be found here https://obstatic1.danskespil.dk/static/compressed/js/ob/slip/crunched.pkg.js?ver=0305f181cb96b61490e0fd2adafa3a91

Comment: you can attach the function to the `window` or `document` global object, which are accessible via console.

Comment: Are you trying to call `betSlipView`, `stakeOnKeyUp`, or something else?

Comment: @KevinHe Thanks! Now I can call the function as if I had set a breakpoint. But is there any way to call the function without using the Chrome debugger tool (i.e. just by using javascript)?

Comment: @Bergi `stakeOnKeyUp` which defined for `betSlipView` but now that Kevin He has gave the idea to attach it to the window, I wonder if it is possible to accomplish this or something similar with javascript only and NOT using chrome tools

Comment: @asd Hi I'm a bit confused .. I don't understand why you want to call it ***Chrome console?*** but now you want to call it without ***Chrome debugger tool***?

Comment: Exactly :)) Could have been clearer, sry.